# BIOS screen edges cut off when displaying over HDMI to TV

Tags: bios, grub, hdmi, tv

I've connected my desktop computer's HDMI output to one of my TV's HDMI inputs, but when I boot up into the computer's BIOS, the left and right edges of the BIOS screen are cut off significantly. The same happens if I boot into an Ubuntu Server GRUB bootloader. But if the system boots fully to a command prompt, then the full screen is visible.

How can I view the full screen on my TV? I don't mind if it's stretched or distorted.
The reason it's important is I can't see certain BIOS settings or what the GRUB bootloader is displaying. The TV is the only display I have.

My motherboard is an [ASUS Prime B460M-A](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/All-series/PRIME-B460M-A/HelpDesk_Manual/) and my TV is a [TCL 55P605](https://www.tcl.com/us/en/products/home-theater/p-series/tcl-55-class-p-series-4k-uhd-hdr-roku-smart-tv-55p605).

I've tried every "Picture Size" adjustment on the TV (Auto, Direct, Normal, Stretch, Zoom) but the edges of my computer BIOS screen and bootloader screen are still not visible.

Comment: Look in your TVs setting for overscan options

Comment: Look in the settings for your TV for an "overscan" setting. According to [this](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/asin/B06Y6FSV5Q/49/ref=ask_ql_psf_ql_hza?isAnswered=true) there should be one. "Yes, in the option section do you have 5 choices for screen sizes including direct mode, with no overscan. "

Comment: I tried the "Direct" mode of "Picture Size" but the edges were still cut off. I don't see any other overscan setting

Comment: `But if the system boots fully to a command prompt, then the full screen is visible.` Sounds like an issue of the GOP driver of the UEFI firmware. `The reason it's important is I can't see certain BIOS settings or what the GRUB bootloader is displaying.` This does not sound like overscan at all.

Answer (score 0):

My tv had this issue with not seeing the left side, there's a "horizontal adjustment" setting in the "size and position" section of the menu. You gotta manually center the display. There's another setting for "width stretch". I have a Vizio so mine might be different